# Malformed URL no protocol error

Tags: java

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "localhost/uatpw/ActiveTransaction"?isx=E13F42EC5E38
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
```

Malformed URL exception when reading data from url containing localhost.

Actually my program is as below

```
package bll.sap;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import utility.PropertyUtility;

public class GetActiveData 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sapURL = "";

        try {


            sapURL = PropertyUtility.getSapURL();


            //Get Summary Data
            SapDataSync sapDataSync = new SapDataSync();

            //sapDataSync.readTransactionJsonFromUrl(sapURL+"?isx=false");
            sapDataSync.readTransactionJsonFromUrl(sapURL+"?isx=E13F42EC5E38");

            } 
        catch(MalformedURLException me)
        {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }   
        catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }









}
```

AND

```
package bll.sap;




    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;

    import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
    import net.sf.json.JSONException;
    import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
    import utility.Utility;

    import com.google.code.morphia.Datastore;

    import dal.GetMorphiaDB;

    public class SapDataSync 
    {

        private void saveSapTransaction(List<TransactionUnit> sapTransaction){
            GetMorphiaDB morphia;
            try {
                morphia = GetMorphiaDB.getInstance();
                Datastore ds = morphia.getDs();
                ds.save(sapTransaction);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void createSapTransaction(String transactionJson){
            JSONObject jsonObj = JSONObject.fromObject(transactionJson);

            JSONArray transactionUnits = jsonObj.getJSONArray("TRANSACTION");


            List<ActiveUnit> transactionList = new ArrayList<ActiveUnit>();
            for(int i = 0; i < transactionUnits.size() ; i++){
                JSONObject jsn = transactionUnits.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject jsnFeed = transactionUnits.getJSONObject(i);

                ActiveUnit transactionUnit = new ActiveUnit(
                        jsn.getString("listEditions"),
                        jsn.getString("listPackage"),
                        //Double.parseDouble(jsn.getString("YIELD")),
                        //Double.parseDouble(jsn.getString("QUANTITY")),
                        //Double.parseDouble(jsn.getString("VALUE")),
                        jsn.getString("referenceID")
                        //jsn.getString("PRICEGROUP"),
                        //jsn.getString("PAGE"),
                        //Utility.getCalendarTime(jsn.getString("PUBDATE"), "dd-MM-yyyy"),
                        //jsn.getString("CLIENTNAME"),
                        //jsn.getString("CLIENTCODE"),
                        // new Date().getTime(),
                         //jsn.getString("BOOKINGUNITNAME"),
                            //jsn.getString("BCCNAME"),
                            //jsn.getString("PAGENAME"),
                        //  jsn.getString("PRICEGROUPNAME"),
                        //  jsn.getString("ORDER"),
                        //  jsn.getString("PAGE_LH_RH")
                        );
                transactionList.add(transactionUnit);
                System.out.println(transactionList);    
            }

            System.out.println(transactionList.size());
            if (transactionList.size() > 0) {
                //saveSapTransaction(transactionList);
            }

        }

        public void readTransactionJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
            InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
            try {
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              int cp;
              while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char) cp);
              }
              createSapTransaction(sb.toString());
            } finally {
              is.close();
            }
          }

    }
```

AND

```
package bll.sap;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Id;

@Entity("SapTransaction")
public class ActiveUnit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private Long  tilCreationDate;
    private String clientName;
    private String clientCode;
    private String listEditions;
    private Long date;
    private String listPackage;
    private String bookingUnitName;
    private String referenceID;
    private String bccName;
    private String page;
    private String pageName;
    private String priceGroup;
    private String pgName;
    private Double yield;
    private Double qty;
    private Double value;
    private String order;
    private String pageType;

    public ActiveUnit() {
    }
    public ActiveUnit(String listEdtions, String listPackage, /*Double yield,
            Double qty, Double value,*/ String referenceID  /*, String priceGroup,
            String page, Long date,String clientName,
            String clientCode,Long  tilCreationDate,String bookingUnitName,String bccName,String pageName,String pgName,String order,String pageType*/) {
        this.listEditions = listEdtions;
        this.listPackage = listPackage;
        //this.yield = yield;
        //this.qty = qty;
        //this.value = value;
        this.referenceID = referenceID;
        //this.priceGroup = priceGroup;
        //this.page = page;
        //this.date = date;
        //this.clientName = clientName;
        //this.clientCode = clientCode;
        //this.tilCreationDate = tilCreationDate;
        //this.setBookingUnitName(bookingUnitName);
        //this.bccName = bccName;
        //this.pageName = pageName;
        //this.pgName = pgName;
        //this.order = order;
        //this.pageType = pageType;
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public String getClientCode() {
        return clientCode;
    }

    public void setClientCode(String clientCode) {
        this.clientCode = clientCode;
    }

    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setTilCreationDate(Long tilCreationDate) {
        this.tilCreationDate = tilCreationDate;
    }

    public Long getTilCreationDate() {
        return tilCreationDate;
    }
    public String getreferenceID() {
        return referenceID;
    }

    public void setreferenceID(String referenceID) {
        this.referenceID = referenceID;
    }

    public String getPriceGroup() {
        return priceGroup;
    }

    public void setPriceGroup(String priceGroup) {
        this.priceGroup = priceGroup;
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public Long getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


    public String getListEditions() {
        return listEditions;
    }

    public void setVertical(String listEditions) {
        this.listEditions = listEditions;
    }

    public String getListPackage() {
        return listPackage;
    }

    public void setListPackage(String listPackage) {
        this.listPackage = listPackage;
    }

    public Double getYield() {
        return yield;
    }

    public void setYield(Double yield) {
        this.yield = yield;
    }

    public Double getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(Double qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setBookingUnitName(String bookingUnitName) {
        this.bookingUnitName = bookingUnitName;
    }

    public String getBookingUnitName() {
        return bookingUnitName;
    }

    public String getBccName() {
        return bccName;
    }

    public void setBccName(String bccName) {
        this.bccName = bccName;
    }

    public String getPageName() {
        return pageName;
    }

    public void setPageName(String pageName) {
        this.pageName = pageName;
    }

    public String getPgName() {
        return pgName;
    }

    public void setPgName(String pgName) {
        this.pgName = pgName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String unit = "{ " +
                            //"ClientCode: "  + this.clientCode+
                            //",TILCreation Date: "  + new Date(this.tilCreationDate)+
                            //",ClientName: "+ this.clientName+
                            "listEditions: "  + this.listEditions+
                            ",listPackage: "+ this.listPackage+ 
                            //",BookingUnitName: "+ this.bookingUnitName+ 
                            //",Yield: "     + this.yield+
                            //",QTY: "  + this.qty+
                            //",Value: "  + this.value+
                            ",referenceID: "  + this.referenceID+
                            //",Price Group: "  + this.priceGroup+
                            //",BCCName: "  + this.bccName+
                            //",PageName: "  + this.pageName+
                            //",PriceGroupName: "  + this.pgName+
                            //",Page: "  + this.page+
                            //",PageType: "  + this.pageType+
                            //",Order: "  + this.order+
                            //",PublishDate: "  + new Date(this.date) +

                    " }";
        return unit;
    }
    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
    public void setPageType(String pageType) {
        this.pageType = pageType;
    }
    public String getPageType() {
        return pageType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's right - it's not a valid URL. What's your question?

Comment: Share your code too..

Comment: now delete all your code... its not necessary for the question. The answer can be found in the exception stack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, make sure you have the protocol set for your request.

Second, make sure that the `String` containing the URL is URL-encoded. I.e. the URL doesn't have any spaces and other special characters - these should be encoded (space is %20 etc).

Given that the two above are met, your program should not throw an exception from the `java.net.URL` class.

Looking at the exception above, you'll just have to set the protocol (`http://`), but do make sure that you encode your URL address strings properly or else you'll get exceptions from other parts of your program.

Also, adding `http://` to the following string will also result in a `MalformedURLException`:
`"localhost/uatpw/ActiveTransaction"?isx=E13F42EC5E38` as your URL would contain special characters (`"` in this case) which would need to be encoded.

To provide a valid URL you should make sure that the quotes are stripped from your URL's server and path segments areas:
`localhost/uatpw/ActiveTransaction?isx=E13F42EC5E38`. Prepeding `http://` to this will result in a valid URL.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the protocol (e.g. `http://`) in front of localhost.

The welformed URL could be `http://localhost/uatpw/ActiveTransaction`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question. What are you trying to do?

But otherwise, "localhost/uatpw/ActiveTransaction" is not a valid URL. An url must start with a protocol (http, https, ftp, etc.).

You should try with:

```
http://localhost/uatpw/ActiveTransaction
```

Comment: I tried by appending http at the begining of the URL but still getting same error

Comment: @yatinbc: tell us the **exact** new URL that you're trying.

Comment: THe same you told ,it is http://localhost/uatpw/ActiveTransaction