# Android JSON image download throw MalformedURLException that is already caught

Tags: android, json, multithreading, reddit

I am downloading images from url's provided by a JSON document. At first my app seems to be working correctly, pulling in and placing images and catching the exceptions when there is no image url in the array element but suddenly it crashes and my error log is showing something to the tune of 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
The thing is I have already caught this error as shown below.

If someone could explain to me why this is happening to me and point me in the right direction I will be much obliged.

**Image DwnLdr class**

```
 public Drawable loadImage (BaseAdapter adapt, ImageView view)
{
    this.adapter = adapt;
    String url = (String) view.getTag();
    if (imageCache.containsKey(url))
    {
        return imageCache.get(url);
    }
    else {
        new ImageTask().execute(url);
        return DEFAULT_ICON;
    }
}

private class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>
{
    private String s_url;

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
        s_url = params[0];
        InputStream inStream;
        try {
            Log.v(debugTag, "Fetching: " + s_url);
            URL url = new URL(s_url);
            inStream = url.openStream();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.v(debugTag, "Malformed: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(debugTag, "I/O : " + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }
        return Drawable.createFromStream(inStream, "src");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        synchronized (this) {
            imageCache.put(s_url, result);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**View Adapter Class**

```
 ListData data = topics.get(position);
    try {
        long lg = Long.valueOf(data.getPostTime())*1000;
        Date date = new  Date(lg);
        String postTime = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy hh:mma").format(date);

        holder.data = data;
        holder.listName.setText(data.getTitle());
        holder.authorName.setText(data.getAuthor());
        holder.postTime.setText(postTime);
        holder.redditScore.setText(data.getrScore());

        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Cell Created");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,"Cell Not Created Due to: ",e);
    }

    if(data.getImageUrl()!=null){
        try {
            holder.thumbnail.setTag(data.getImageUrl());


            Drawable drawable = imgGet.loadImage(this, holder.thumbnail);
      if (drawable != null) {
                holder.thumbnail.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            } else {
                holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.filler_icon);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,"no image: ",e);

        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

**Main Class Adapter Set**

```
public static class MyViewHolder {
    public TextView listName, authorName, redditScore, postTime;
    public Button goButton;
    public ImageView thumbnail;
    public ListData data;
}
public void setTopics(ArrayList<ListData> data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.postList.setAdapter(new RedditDataAdapter(this, this.getImg, this.layoutInflater,this.data));

}
```

**Error Log**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
        at Tasks.RedditIconTask$ImageTask.doInBackground(RedditIconTask.java:60)
        at Tasks.RedditIconTask$ImageTask.doInBackground(RedditIconTask.java:46)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Malformed URL no protocol error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146048/malformed-url-no-protocol-error)

Comment: But I caught that error? My app is crashing due to a different error.

Comment: I looked further into my log and you were right it is a MalformedURLEception but I caught already I thought. This is downloading from reddit which either returns a proper url or the string "nsfw" what do I do?

Comment: Just wondering why you use e.printStackTrace() as well as Log.v(tag, message, throwable)? Isn't just the log message sufficient?

Comment: @Kartik_Koro ahh i recycled the code and was to lazy to delete it, i find the Logs easier to spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the image URL is an empty string. Debug your code to learn why is it so. The code you posted doesn't really show where the URL value comes from.

Why you're getting the exception is because you're re-throwing it, wrapped in a `RuntimeException`:

```
throw new RuntimeException(e);
```

Comment: My logs tell me the urls either come in correctly or as "nsfw" which is not a url as i said in the description. Why would throwing an error to catch it actually cause it?

Comment: Okay I got rid of the throw new RuntimeException(e) and did a work around and now I've got it to work correctly, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by using what laatlto said and changing the code to the following.

```
protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
        s_url = params[0];
        InputStream inStream;
        Drawable picture=null;
        try {
            Log.v(debugTag, "Fetching: " + s_url);


            URL url = new URL(s_url);
            inStream = url.openStream();
            picture= Drawable.createFromStream(inStream, "src");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.v(debugTag, "Malformed: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(debugTag, "I/O : " + e.getMessage());

        }
        return picture;
    }
```